# How to execute linux kernel without kexec?

Tags: android, linux, arm

I want to exec linux kernel 's zImage while I have booted another linux kernel . I saw KEXEC but I can not use it because I can not recompile my kernel with kexec support . so my question is , how to do that without kexec ?
( I am using Android Kernel )

Answer (score 1):

Usually you need a boot loader to load a kernel image. Kexec is the other option. If you have the secondary kernel image pre-loaded to some memory location by something else, you can add a trigger in /proc or similar to perform a soft reboot to the new location. (see arch/arm/kernel/process.c for soft-restart). If you can't compile the kernel with kexec and can not use a userspace tool, your primary kernel will have to perform filesystem read/write directly which is not a recommended way.

Comment: Can I compile Kexec as a standalone tool without compiling kernel?

Comment: kexec has two parts. The userspace part called kexec tools and the support for kexec in kernel. The userspace tools will not work without the kernel support enabled. ie, without kernel support, the kexec system call will not be available. You can try building the kernel kexec support as a module. Features other than panic kernel should work without memory reserved at boot time.